# Return NULL values last in an ordered set

Tags: sql

I have a set of values in a temp table, which I want to use to populate three new columns (in the `MAX(CASE ... END)` statement below).

However, I find that sometimes Column 1 (or both Column 1 and Column 2) will contain `NULL` values, even though Column 3 has a value.

What I would like is for any `NULL` values to appear *after* other values, e.g., Col1 = value, Col2 = value, Col3 = `NULL`.

Source Code:

```
 SELECT 
     mc.ID 
    ,mc.Date 
    ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 1 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col1
    ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 2 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col2
    ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 3 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col3
INTO #Total7
FROM  
    #MyTable3 as mc  
     join
      (
        select 
            #MyTable3.*,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date]) as row_num
        from #MyTable3 
      )as sv1 on 
        mc.ID = sv1.ID 
GROUP BY 
    mc.ID
    ,mc.Date

SELECT * 
FROM #Total7
ORDER BY ID, Date
```

Comment: What do you mean `NULL` should never proceed a value?

Comment: null should never preceed a value?

Comment: OP if `max(case when sv1.row_num = 1 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col1 results in a `NULL` then the value will be `NULL`. I don't understand your question.

Comment: What you see is just dummy data. What I want to know is whether I need to add something to the code so that a value will always sit in Col1 and or Col2 followed by any Null values. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Kello if `sv1.[Col]` is `NULL` then why would you want to arbitrarily change it's value? If you just want it to not be `NULL` in column 1 then add `ISNULL` to `sv1.[Col]` or add an `ELSE` to your case statement.

Comment: You can do case col1 is null(case col2 is null(col3, col2), col1)

Comment: add where [Col] is not null to you subquery for sv1

Comment: @Zane  I don't mind Null values. But I just don't want it to proceed a value. I was wondering whether I needed to stick a -1 somewhere in the code just to shunt everything to the left! Helpful?

Comment: Change this phrase (`row_number() over(partition by [ID] order by [Date]) as row_num`) to (`row_number() over(partition by [ID] order by ISNULL([Date], '12/31/9999')) as row_num`)`. NULL always shows up first in an `ORDER BY`.  If necessary, you could change the date I put in there to something else that is farther in the future than you ever expect to see.

Comment: Also, the word is ["Precede"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/precede) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your values are showing up in that order because [NULL is always the first value returned by an ORDER BY](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/why-are-nulls-sorted-first), and that's what you are using within the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to sort your records (determining whether a value belongs in Col1, Col2, or Col3).  Change your query to:

```
SELECT 
     mc.ID 
    ,mc.Date 
    ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 1 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col1
    ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 2 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col2
    ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 3 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col3
INTO #Total7
FROM  
    #MyTable3 as mc  
     join
      (
        select 
            #MyTable3.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY ISNULL([Date], '12/31/9999')) as row_num
        from #MyTable3 
      )as sv1 on 
        mc.ID = sv1.ID 
GROUP BY 
    mc.ID
    ,mc.Date

SELECT * 
FROM #Total7
ORDER BY ID, Date
```

The `ISNULL()` function will, if the `[Date]` field is null, return instead a date that is far into the future.  Thus, any 'real' dates will show up with the first row number value, and any `NULL` dates will show up last.

Or, if you don't like `ISNULL()`, you could use a `CASE` statement, i.e.,

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
      (
        PARTITION BY [ID] 
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN [Date] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            [Date]
      ) as row_num
```

Comment: Didn't work. There are no Null dates. The issue appears to arise with 2 or more records with the same Id but different dates. Helpful?

Comment: If there are more than three actual dates for the ID, then yes I would expect to see no NULL values.

Answer (score 0):

Add date to your join query.

```
     SELECT 
         mc.ID 
        ,mc.Date 
        ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 1 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col1
        ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 2 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col2
        ,max(case when sv1.row_num = 3 and mc.Date = sv1.Date then sv1.[Col] end) as Col3
    INTO #Total7
    FROM  
        #MyTable3 as mc  
         join
          (
            select 
                #MyTable3.*,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date]) as row_num
            from #MyTable3 
          )as sv1 on 
            mc.ID = sv1.ID 
            and mc.Date = sv1.Date
    GROUP BY 
        mc.ID
        ,mc.Date

    SELECT * 
    FROM #Total7
    ORDER BY ID, Date
```